# Non-reflective boundary condition

Tags: pde, fluid-dynamics, boundary-conditions

I'm currently solving incompressible Navier-Stokes system of equations with periodic flow and high viscosity.

Is there any outlet boundary types that avoids the reflection of flow from the outlet back into the computational domain? (Neumann is not sufficient).

Update:

Left: $u = C  sin (\alpha y + \beta t) + u_0$

Top: open

Bot: wall

Right: open

Comment: Have a look at complex absorbing potentials.

Comment: Can you write down your PDE?

Comment: It crucially depends on what your PDE is. You probably want to state the model you're using for your flow.

Comment: A method I know is the so called "perfectly matched layer" (PML). Note that this is equivalent to the method that @davidhight already mentioned. You find a section about PML in this book : Kaltenbacher, Manfred. Numerical simulation of mechatronic sensors and actuators. Vol. 2. Berlin: Springer, 2007.

Comment: @nicoguaro its incompressible Navier Stokes

Comment: @NewB Please edit your question to include this piece of information. But it's worth pointing out that the N-S equations are not an elliptic equation.

Comment: @WolfgangBangerth did, thank you

Comment: Do you get a flow reflected into your domain with periodic boundary conditions?

Comment: I too am confused about this. Either you have outlet boundary conditions, or periodic boundary conditions. You can't have both...

Comment: @WolfgangBangerth periodic inlet on one side, outlet on opposite.

Comment: If you have periodic inlet it means that the (velocity) function is periodic in your domain, so it should be the same that you get in the outlet, doesn't it?

Comment: Or do you mean "periodic in x-direction", "outlet in positive y-direction"?

This whole confusion about what precisely you mean suggests that it would be useful to be more precise in your question. Show us a diagram of what you want to do, write down what you mean by "Neumann boundary condition", show us a solution that illustrates why what you are currently doing is not sufficient. Help us understand your question!

Comment: I agree that if it is periodic on one side it should be periodic on the other side. If I have well understood the problem, in my opinion, there is an outlet boundary condition on the right side and inlet on the left. The domain is probably not enough long to let the flow develop and, what you call reflecting, actually are artifacts due to the vortex that cannot be captured (it is because of recirculation that you have this). See my answer below for a possible solution. Otherwise specify better a scheme with the domain and bcs.

Comment: I give up. You only provided half of the information requested. You don't say what "open boundary" is supposed to mean, you don't say what "wall" is supposed to mean mathematically, you don't show a picture, and you provide a boundary condition for the left boundary that only provides a scalar when the N-S equations require you to provide the full velocity *vector*. People here can't be expected to keep asking questions if you want to get an answer to your post.

Comment: @WolfgangBangerth that is why asking here, im looking for mathematical representation of an open boundaries with wall at the bottom. by wall I meant $\frac{\partial P}{\partial n}=0$ and no slip conditions. flow is horizontal, no vertical inflow. my bad.

Comment: But you can't impose the condition $\partial P/\partial n$ for the Navier-Stokes equations. It is mathematically not possible to do so, nor is there a physical situation where that would be the case.

Comment: @WolfgangBangerth https://scicomp.stackexchange.com/questions/37150/projection-method-fvm-poisson-part-adding-source-term strange that no one pointed me out earlier, apologies for the inconvenience. Will read through it again. Thank you for your time!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Even if it is not completely physical in some computational FV codes like OpenFOAM exist something called "inletOutlet" boundary condition that make the speed 0 at the boundary when it assumes negative values (or opposite to the sign of your outlet condition). You can find an explanation [here](https://www.cfdsupport.com/OpenFOAM-Training-by-CFD-Support/node114.html) and [here](https://www.openfoam.com/documentation/guides/latest/doc/guide-bcs-outlet-inlet-outlet.html). Even if it can be a solution, I suggest you to analyse again the physics of your problem and probably one better solution would be to use a longer domain and standard Neumann.

[image]